# Full Text Search only performs 'starts with' searches

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Pretty basic question, but how can I get the `containstable` search to do an actual 'contains' search, rather than a 'starts with' one?

For example, from [the examples in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples):

```
CREATE TABLE Flags (Country nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, FlagColors varchar(200));  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX FlagKey ON Flags(Country);  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('France', 'Blue and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Italy', 'Green and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Tanzania', 'Green and Yellow and Black and Yellow and Blue');  
SELECT * FROM Flags;  
GO  

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG TestFTCat;  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Flags(FlagColors) KEY INDEX FlagKey ON TestFTCat;  
GO   

SELECT * FROM Flags;  
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green') ORDER BY RANK DESC;  
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green or Black') ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

Works fine, and so does:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, '"Gree*"') ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, '"*reen"') ORDER BY RANK DESC;  
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, '"*reen*"') ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

Should I be using a different query, or is what I'm looking for not possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is, I think, a common misconception when it comes to full text search in SQL Server.

Full Text Search enables searching for entire words as well as a number of other things.  From the [`CONTAINS` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> CONTAINS can search for:
>
> - A word or phrase.
> - **The prefix of a word or phrase.**
> - A word near another word.
> - A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).
> - A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and "steel").

So just like with normal indexes on text strings, you can do *prefix* searching.

Neither full text search, nor normal SQL Server indexes, support "postfix" or "contains" searching *within* a word or text string.  So no leading wildcards, essentially.

Note that the same limitations apply to [`CONTAINSTABLE`:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)

> CONTAINSTABLE is useful for the same kinds of matches as the CONTAINS predicate and uses the same search conditions as CONTAINS.

I imagine these limitations exist because of the way indexes are logically stored in SQL Server - as b-trees, where it's very easy to "jump" or "seek" to the different parts of an index based on the *start* of the data in the indexed column.